# Python, oracle. Возврат к началу после получения ответов

Tags: python, telebot, cx-oracle

Проблемам примерно состоит в неверном написании `IF,elif,else` хочу вернуться к старту либо к предыдущему меню но не могу верно написать код в последнем `def` где запрос к БД так как выводятся два сообщения сразу а надо или

```
    def start(message):
    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton('Код товара'), types.KeyboardButton('Наименование товара'))
    
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбирете желаемое", reply_markup=rmk)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_unswer)


def user_unswer(message):
    if message.text == "Код товара":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите код товара")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_reg)
    elif message.text == "Наименование товара":
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На данный момент этот пункт не работает!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Еще раз повторяю не работает!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
def user_reg(message):
    res=sql.execute(f"SELECT skucode, name from sku where skucode = '{message.text}'")
    res=sql.fetchall()
    for row in res:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Код товара: {res[0][0]}\nНаименование: {res[0][1]}")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
```

Суть в том что если `sql.fetchall()` не может получить данные то требуется вывести сообщение "Данные введены не верно, либо отсутствуют записи" и после этого должен быть возврат к этому же пункту 'user_reg'

Comment: Если я после ' msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Код товара: {res[0][0]}\nНаименование: {res[0][1]}")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)' добавляю 'else' то при верном запросе бот выводит два сообщения

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_reg(message):
res=sql.execute(f"SELECT skucode, name from sku where skucode = '{message.text}'")
res=sql.fetchall()
if res:
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Код товара: {res[0][0]}\nНаименование: {res[0][1]}")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
else:
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Данные введены не корректно, либо отсутствуют в БД")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_reg)
```